# Div is smaller than the content of the Div

Tags: html, css

I've a `DIV`, with a `button` inside. Under this `DIV`, I've a `hr`, but the `hr` isn't under the `button`. I could make the `DIV` height bigger, but I don't know how high the `button` is (it depends on the browser). Can I style the `DIV`, that all things, which are in the code under the `DIV`, on the website also under the `DIV` are? I show below my HTML and the CSS code, and a screenshot from the result.

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

/* centering the div that is supposed to take all content */
#center {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#wrapper {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: -1px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  height: 75vh;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 75vh;
}

hr {
  border-style: none;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

#output {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* make button sit on the right side */
#copy {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="center">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top">
      <div id="output"></div>
      <div id="copy"><button>kopieren</button></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Your code has alot of `div` elements. Which one are you having problems with?

Comment: Can you add an image of how you want it to look like?

Comment: @MSC Only English is allowed on this platform. This also applies to comments.

Comment: Children/descendants that  `float` are not considered when the browser calculates the height of an element. A `div` that contains only floating elements will have a height of `0`.

Comment: To be more clear: The problem results from your button floating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your problem that you want the `hr` to be placed under the button? Then, applying a `width: 100%` to it could be a solution. But it depends on the final result you're looking for.

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
}


/* Schriftart (Sansserif), Weiss */

body {
  background-image: url(img.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
}


/* positioning background image */

#center {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* centering the div that is supposed to take all content */

#wrapper {
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: -1px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  height: 75vh;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 75vh;
}

hr {
  border-style: none;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

#output {
  display: inline-block;
}

#copy {
  float: right;
}


/* make button sit on the right side */

button {
  background-color: rgb(132, 60, 116);
  border: none;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="center">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top">
      <div id="output"></div>
      <div id="copy"><button>kopieren</button></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
#top {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Here is the result

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
}


/* Schriftart (Sansserif), Weiss */

body {
  background-image: url(img.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
}


/* positioning background image */

#center {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* centering the div that is supposed to take all content */

#wrapper {
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: -1px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  height: 75vh;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 75vh;
}

hr {
  border-style: none;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

#output {
  display: inline-block;
}

#copy {
  float: right;
}


/* make button sit on the right side */

button {
  background-color: rgb(132, 60, 116);
  border: none;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#top {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="center">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top">
      <div id="output"></div>
      <div id="copy"><button>kopieren</button></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```